# Make actual URL unavailable in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have written a rule in my routes.php file in Code Igniter. Something like the following

```
$route['user/profile'] = 'user/User_actions/user_profile';
```

What I want is to make the URL `user/User_actions/user_profile` unavailable through the browser. Is there any possible way to achieve this in CodeIgniter?

Comment: why would you want to route to an unavailable url?

Comment: It is because of the requests that are specific to only ```user/profile``` and if someone types ```user/User_actions/user_profile``` in the url then they won't work and will throw an error which I don't want.

Comment: you need to control this with some kind of auth system, like [Ion-auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) or similar and control access through sessions which were set by the auth system